# Inno Setup script (.iss) syntax highlight in Sublime Text?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublime-text

I'm working on the Inno Setup based installer. I'd prefer to edit the script file in Sublime Text, but it doesn't appear to detect the language and doesn't enable syntax highlighting. I have failed so far to find a plugin for Inno Setup highlighting.

If such plugin does not exist, maybe there's a syntax highlighting that is not a perfect match, but looks reasonably meaningful to edit the script in comfort? If so, what is the syntax highlighting and how to enable it?

Comment: I see two close votes have been cast. Why is the question off-topic?

Comment: I was confused whether to write to Stack Overflow or here, but in the end decided that the question is about using software (essentially a text editor). So the question is not an actual programming question even if I'm using the editor to program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package for Inno Setup (syntax definitions, completions and build system), available on [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Inno%20Setup).

Comment: Yes! Apparently it's only available for Sublime Text 3, that's why I couldn't find it. I've [upgraded](http://wesbos.com/migrating-to-sublime-text-3/), finally, and it works well.

Comment: The package only started to require Sublime Text 3 with the latest update. Should you have reason to go back to Sublime Text 2, you can install the package in version 5.x!

Comment: When I attempted to just install the package in Sublime Text 2, I have pressed `Ctrl+Shift+P`, selected "Package Control: Install Package" and searched for "Inno", but didn't find anything. Is there a way to install an old package version via Package Control? *(I don't really think I'll need it, I'm quite satisfied with ST3 so far...)*

Comment: Just for the record: the package now supports both versions (again)